# React Native Navigation :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

React Native Navigation looks like the best choice to navigate between scenes in react native, but i can't install it in my android project.I'm sure i followed everything as the docs says, [but it shows this error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GJPq_yoETemWF7nFH6EodSlb0nw9rWMZ)

This is the full build (Stackoverflow does not allow large blocks of code, so I've just identified what looks wrong):

```
C:\wixNav>react-native run-android
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\wixNav\node_modules (25ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Observed package id 'system-images;android-26;android-wear;x86' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\felip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-26\android-wear-cn\x86' (Expected 'C:\Users\felip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-26\android-wear\x86')

Observed package id 'system-images;android-26;android-wear;x86' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\felip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-26\android-wear-cn\x86' (Expected 'C:\Users\felip\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-26\android-wear\x86')

downloadRobolectricDependencies C:\wixNav\android\build/robolectric-dependencies
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:checkReleaseManifest
:react-native-navigation:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComAurelhubertAhbottomnavigation206Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComBalysvMaterialmenuMaterialMenu154Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComBalysvMaterialmenuMaterialMenuToolbar154Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0533Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
:react-native-navigation:prepareReleaseDependencies
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseAidl
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:compileLint
:react-native-navigation:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseRenderscript
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseResValues
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseResources
:react-native-navigation:mergeReleaseResources
:react-native-navigation:processReleaseManifest
:react-native-navigation:processReleaseResources
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseSources
:react-native-navigation:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:react-native-navigation:extractReleaseAnnotations
:react-native-navigation:mergeReleaseShaders
:react-native-navigation:compileReleaseShaders
:react-native-navigation:generateReleaseAssets
:react-native-navigation:mergeReleaseAssets
:react-native-navigation:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:packageReleaseResources
:react-native-navigation:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-navigation:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:react-native-navigation:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:react-native-navigation:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:react-native-navigation:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:react-native-navigation:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:react-native-navigation:bundleRelease
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library
:app:prepareComAurelhubertAhbottomnavigation206Library
:app:prepareComBalysvMaterialmenuMaterialMenu154Library
:app:prepareComBalysvMaterialmenuMaterialMenuToolbar154Library
 :app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0533Library
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library
:app:prepareWixNavReactNativeNavigationUnspecifiedLibrary
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:mergeDebugShaders
:app:compileDebugShaders
:app:generateDebugAssets
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
C:\wixNav\android\app\src\main\java\com\wixnav\MainApplication.java:71: error: class, interface, or enum expected
public String getJSMainModuleName() {
       ^
C:\wixNav\android\app\src\main\java\com\wixnav\MainApplication.java:73: error: class, interface, or enum expected
}
^
2 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 36.407 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Then i executed npm install and it displayed this:

```
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareWixNavReactNativeNavigationUnspecifiedLibrary FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:prepareWixNavReactNativeNavigationUnspecifiedLibrary'.
> Could not expand ZIP 'C:\wixNav\node_modules\react-native-navigation\android\app\build\outputs\aar\react-native-navigation-release.aar'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.285 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

My MainAplication.java:

```
package com.wixnav;
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationReactPackage;
import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.reactnativenavigation.NavigationApplication;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new NavigationReactPackage(),
            new NavigationReactPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}

 public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication {

     @Override
     public boolean isDebug() {
         // Make sure you are using BuildConfig from your own application
         return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
     }

     protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
         // Add additional packages you require here
         // No need to add RnnPackage and MainReactPackage
         return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
             // eg. new VectorIconsPackage()
         );
     }

     @Override
     public List<ReactPackage> createAdditionalReactPackages() {
         return getPackages();
     }

     @Override
public String getJSMainModuleName() {
    return "index";
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getJSMainModuleName() {
       ^
MainApplication.java:73: error: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Sounds like you tried to define that method at the top level. You can't do that in Java. All of your methods have to be inside of a class.

Comment: Ok, there was an Override method out of the class, but know is saying that I have a duplicated class(https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hnBFwJ4aI0E50yxeXqTLOYVkl0MJlvBd), but the docs jus say to add the code with a new class
I'will edit the question adding my MainAplication.java

Comment: I've copied from the example in github(you just keeps the first line with "packege yourprojectsname"). And yes, the example is diferent from the docs. So now it compiles but the app dont open, just say it has stopped

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: When the docs say to modify some file, go to the example on github and copy what is there, just don't do it in the lines your projects name is required

Answer (score 0):

You declared MainApplication twice. After you pasted the

```
 public class MainApplication extends NavigationApplication { ...
```

from the documentation. You should remove the original definition of MainApplication, which is the code below

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new NavigationReactPackage(),
            new NavigationReactPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```